# Are taxi drivers in Bangkok expected to round up the taxi fare to the nearest multiple of 10 THB?

Tags: thailand, local-customs, taxis, fares, bangkok

For example, if the taxi fare is 53 THB and I give 60 THB (for lack of coins), the taxi drivers typically will not give any change back. I wonder whether this is because I don't look Thai or because it is the tradition here for taxi fares not to give change back if below 10 THB.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[According to TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g293915-s606/Thailand:Tipping.And.Etiquette.html), in taxis, "both Thais and local ex-pats commonly round up the fare (i.e. 51 baht fare rounded up to 60 baht)." As ฿7 is equivalent to US$0.22, I wouldn't worry about it much.

Comment: A nice 17.6% tip, though. Of course, if the fare happens to be 59 baht, it is only a 1.7% tip, so I guess it evens out. And indeed, if the fare is from 51 to 60 baht, the average tip is 8.4%.

Comment: @Graipher finally someone with some financial sense! Not looking at absolute price in some other unrelated currency but looking at the margin.

Comment: 0% - 17.6% margin - how is that "evening out"?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Proper financial sense is to look at the absolute cost, not percentage. Your time is not worth 17% of a one dollar purchase, but it probably is worth 17% of a thousand dollar purchase.

Comment: @BradyGilg Asking for change doesn't take much time. Typically I use this time to check whether I took all my belongings from the taxi.

Answer (score 0):

From https://itsbetterinthailand.com/how-to-use-local-taxis-in-bangkok-without-getting-ripped-off-or-lost/ ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200614203404/https://itsbetterinthailand.com/how-to-use-local-taxis-in-bangkok-without-getting-ripped-off-or-lost/),  [mirror 2](http://archive.is/A4YZj)):

> Tipping is not necessary but it’s common to round up to the nearest 5 or 10 baht.

The same page also gives some interesting advice regarding the case where the taxi driver claims not to have any change (which in my experience does happen once in a while, even for 5 THB change):

> I’ll warn you that if you use a taxi without having 100 baht notes or smaller, you may have trouble getting change from your driver. It’s common to claim “no have change” – and I’m not sure how you’re going to prove that they do. I’ve asked to drive on to a 7-11 before so I could get change – suddenly the driver found some coins in his center console.
>
> Take a selection of 100 and 20 baht notes plus some coins if you want to pay the exact fare.

Comment: Downvoters: any comment for me to improve the answer?